# Simple GLSL example not showing anything on screen

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

I am trying to print a simple cube using GLSL but I only get an empty screen. I don't know what I am doing wrong. The vertices, normals, triangles are exported from Blender.

```
void InitBuffers() {

    // monkey vertices, normals
    readVerticesNormals();

    // cube vertices
    glGenVertexArraysAPPLE(1, &CubeVao);
    glBindVertexArrayAPPLE(CubeVao);

    glGenBuffers(1, &CubeVboPositions);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,CubeVboPositions);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glGenBuffers(1,&CubeVboColors);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, CubeVboColors);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(colors), colors, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glGenBuffers(1, &CubeNormals);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, CubeNormals);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(normals), normals, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glGenBuffers(1, &CubeIbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, CubeIbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(triangles), triangles, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}
```

I bind the vertex data to the shader.

```
glBindAttribLocation(ProgramShader, 0, "position");
glBindAttribLocation(ProgramShader, 1, "color");
glBindAttribLocation(ProgramShader, 2, "normal");
```

Camera is positioned in (0,0,0) looking towards (0,0,-1). The object, in this case the cube, it positioned at (0,0,-4).
The render function is:

```
void display() {

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3d(1,0,0);

    // set view matrix
    ViewMatrix.setView(0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,1,0);

    // use shader program
    glUseProgram(ProgramShader);

    // send uniforms to shader
    glUniformMatrix4fv(ProjectionMatrixLocation, 1, false, ProjectionMatrix.m);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(ViewMatrixLocation, 1, false, ViewMatrix.m);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(ModelMatrixLocation, 1, false, ModelMatrix.m);

    glBindVertexArrayAPPLE(CubeVao);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3*tri_num, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, (void*)0);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Vertex shader:

```
attribute vec3 position;
attribute vec3 color;
attribute vec3 normal;

uniform mat4 modelMatrix,viewMatrix,projMatrix;

varying vec4 Normal;
varying vec4 Position;
varying vec4 Color;

void main() {
    // position in view space
    Position = viewMatrix * modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);

    // normal in view space
    Normal = normalize(viewMatrix * modelMatrix * vec4(normal, 1.0));

    Color = vec4(color, 1.0);

    // final position
    gl_Position = projMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
varying vec4 Normal;
varying vec4 Position;
varying vec4 Color;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = Color;
}
```

Comment: Did you try `gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0);`? This will show you the geometry only (everything is drawn white). If it's still black, your geometry / vertex shader is wrong; if it's not, your colors are wrong. Also, make sure that your shader program is compiled and linked correctly (It's always a good idea to dump the GLSL compiler message)

Comment: What does the compile log say? Are there any OpenGL errors? [How far can you narrow down your code?](http://sscce.org/) Just dumping hundreds of lines of code here is unlike to make anyone help here.

Comment: I have no errors and no warnings. Also, the colors are hard-coded to (0.50, 0.45, 0.87).

Comment: FYI, you cannot transform normals the same way as the position, but that's not why nothing shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Depending how vertices, colors, etc are defined, sizeof(vertices) may just return the size of the pointer. Try:

```
3*numVertices*sizeof(float)
```